# Why is my UITableViewCell malfunctioning?

Tags: swift

Whenever I scroll down to the bottom of my `UITableView` 2 of my `UITableViewCell` are  sharing contents that are supposed to be in their own seperate sections. I am trying to get the UIButton by alone in and the "More Info" label alone.How can I fix this?

[image: image of UITableView]

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) 
  if indexPath.section == 5 {
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            let doneButton = UIButton(type: .system)
            doneButton.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
            doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Done), for: .touchUpInside)
            cell.contentView.addSubview(doneButton)
            doneButton.frame = cell.bounds
            doneButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            doneButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            doneButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor).isActive = true    
        }

        if indexPath.section == 6 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "More Info"
             }
        return cell
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

As cells are reusable and you add the button programmatically here

```
cell.contentView.addSubview(doneButton)
doneButton.frame = cell.bounds
doneButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
doneButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
doneButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

it may appear in the other else , so add a tag to it like

```
doneButton.tag = 222
```

And inside else do

```
if indexPath.section == 6 {
    cell.contentView.subviews.forEach { if($0.tag == 222) { $0.removeFromSuperview() } }
    cell.textLabel?.text = "More Info"
}
```

Comment: After I implemented this code the `UITableView` still looks the same. Is there any other way to change this? I am fairly new to swift and I appreciate your help. Coiuld the problem be from using If statements in `cellForRowAt`?